# How do I use LINQ to find 5 elements in a row that match one predicate, but where the sixth element doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to learn LINQ and it seems that finding a series of 'n' elements that match a predicate should be possible but I can't seem to figure out how to approach the problem.

My solution actually needs a second, different predicate to test the 'end' of the sequence but finding the first element that doesn't past a test, after a sequence of at least 5 elements that *do* pass the test would also be interesting.

Here is my naive non-LINQ approach....

```
 int numPassed = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < array.Count - 1; i++ )
 {
     if (FirstTest(array[i]))
     {
        numPassed++;
     }
     else
     {
        numPassed = 0;
     }

     if ((numPassed > 5) && SecondTest(array[i + 1]))
     {
          foundindex = i;
          break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you give some example input/outputs? To make clear what you want/expect...

Comment: Your code has a crash bug if the sequence happens to include the last element of the array. In any case this is awkward to do in the spirit of LINQ -- what if it's not an array but just an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Jeremy, can you post the solution for "finding a series of 'n' elements that match a predicate"?

Comment: To be honest in this particular case I would stay with for(i).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A performant LINQ solution is possible but frankly quite ugly. The idea is to isolate subsequences that match the description (a series of N items matching a predicate that ends when an item is found that matches a second predicate) and then select the first of these that has a minimum length.

Let's say that the parameters are:

```
var data = new[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

Func<int, bool> acceptPredicate = i => i != 0;

// The reverse of acceptPredicate, but could be otherwise
Func<int, bool> rejectPredicate = i => i == 0;
```

Isolating subsequences is possible with `GroupBy` and a bunch of ugly stateful code (here's the inherent awkwardness -- you have to keep non-trivial state). The idea is to group by an artificial and arbitrary "group number", choosing a different number whenever we move from a subsequence that might be acceptable to one that definitely is not acceptable and when the reverse happens as well:

```
var acceptMode = false;
var groupCount = 0;
var groups = data.GroupBy(i => {
    if (acceptMode && rejectPredicate(i)) {
        acceptMode = false;
        ++groupCount;
    }
    else if (!acceptMode && acceptPredicate(i)) {
        acceptMode = true;
        ++groupCount;
    }
    return groupCount;
});
```

The last step (finding the first group of acceptable length) is easy, but there is one last pitfall: making sure that you don't select one of the groups that do *not* satisfy the stated condition:

```
var result = groups.Where(g => !rejectPredicate(g.First()))
                   .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() >= 5);
```

All of the above is achieved with a single pass over the source sequence.

Note that this code will accept a sequence of items that also ends the source sequence (i.e. it does not terminate because we found an item that satisfies `rejectPredicate` but because we ran out of data). If you don't want this a slight modification will be required.

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/X66uL).

Comment: Side effects inside LINQ operators? That can't end well.

Comment: I think this satisfies both the problem I presented and the spirit of the problem in the generic.

I don't think this is probably the best way in my code now, but it serves as a *great* example of how to (potentially) use LINQ to solve this or similar problems.

Seriously, thanks for helping me with develop my insight into how to approach things with these new tools.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: These side effects are not observable though; it's no different than what e.g. `Single` does (need to keep state to detect duplicates).

Comment: @JeremyWhite: LINQ offers great opportunity for creativity. I 've been "granted insight" myself many times. :)

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, but I can't agree. Taking procedural, non-functional, non-set-based state-machine code and sticking it inside a LINQ operator just so that it can have the "this is LINQ" label slapped on seem like a perversion to me. Making a new LINQ operator out of it, on the other hand, is a different matter. Nevertheless your code is correct, and it does show a way to solve a problem that has problematic constraints to begin with. I just reserve the right not to like it, and ask others to take heed.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: Sure, I don't particularly like the result either (although I did like the challenge). But my point is that a) it's not "foreach with LINQ" as regards side effects and b) sticking this code inside a LINQ operator is a good idea but doesn't really have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Jon: I just read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix.aspx) by Eric Lippert and thought of this discussion. He put it more eloquently than me. The key takeaway is: "**Try to always avoid side effects in queries.**" *[emphasis his]*

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: You *have* to understand that there is a fundamental difference between modifying a variable and a side effect. Eric's example has an *observable side effect*: the values of `success` and `tmp` not only change, but the rest of the program *has to observe these changes* in order to work correctly. My answer has two variables that do get mutated, but *noone is supposed to look at their values apart from the lambda*. If you manually hoist them and the method into a class they could and would be `private`. Please take time to understand the moral before using blanket statements.

Comment: @Jon: *"the values of `success` and `tmp` not only change, but the rest of the program has to observe these changes in order to work correctly"* - not true. `tmp` and `success` are for the exclusive use of the query, they are not supposed to be observed outside of the query, **exactly** like your `acceptMode` and `groupCount` variables, they are essentially "private" variables of the query. Eric's example shows that even with those kinds of variables, the query can stumble over itself due to a hidden coupling between variable state and the item processing order.

Comment: @Jon: If `.GroupBy()` didn't call your lambda in the order you expect, your solution wouldn't work. You're relying on an implementation detail of a LINQ operator. What if in some future version they optimized `.GroupBy()` and didn't call the lambda with the exact order that the items appear in the source collection? That would be a perfectly valid implementation of `.GroupBy()`, since it only ever promises to yield items in the same order they are provided in the source sequence, it does not promise to call the lambda in that order as well (take for example, PLINQ).

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but this will work:

```
var indexList = array
                 .Select((x, i) => new 
                     { Item = x, Index = i })
                 .Where(item => 
                     item.Index + 5 < array.Length && 
                     FirstTest(array[item.Index]) && 
                     FirstTest(array[item.Index+1]) && 
                     FirstTest(array[item.Index+2]) && 
                     FirstTest(array[item.Index+3]) && 
                     FirstTest(array[item.Index+4]) && 
                     SecondTest(array[item.Index+5]))
                 .Select(item => item.Index);
```

Comment: And it doesn't scale very well. E.g. let's say the requirement have changed a little and I need a sequence of 500 matching elements followed by a terminating element. Or the required sequence length is variable and needs to be passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to combine existing extension methods, it is much more cleaner to use an [`Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx).

---

**Example:**

```
IEnumerable<T> MatchThis<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                            Func<T, bool> first_predicate,
                            Int32 times_match,
                            Func<T, bool> second_predicate)
{
    var found = new List<T>();
    using (var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while(en.MoveNext() && found.Count < times_match)
            if (first_predicate((T)en.Current))
                found.Add((T)en.Current);
            else
                found.Clear();

        if (found.Count < times_match && !en.MoveNext() || !second_predicate((T)en.Current))
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        found.Add((T)en.Current);
        return found;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var valid_seq = new Int32[] {800, 3423, 423423, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 200, 433, 32};
var result = MatchThis(valid_seq, e => e<100, 5, e => e>100);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want continuous 6 elements, the first 5 of which match predicate1, and the last (the 6th) matches predicate2. Your non-linq version works fine, using linq in this case is a little reluctant. And trying to resolve the problem in one linq query makes the issue harder, here is a (maybe) cleaner linq solution:

```
int continuous = 5;
var temp = array.Select(n => FirstTest(n) ? 1 : 0);
var result = array.Where((n, index) => 
               index >= continuous 
               && SecondTest(n) 
               && temp.Skip(index - continuous).Take(continuous).Sum() == continuous)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Things will be easier if you have [`Morelinq.Batch` method.](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28)

Comment: I believe after `Skip` you need to add `Take(continuous)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = array.GetSixth(FirstTest).FirstOrDefault(SecondTest);

internal static class MyExtensions
{
      internal static IEnumerable<T> GetSixth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
       {
            var counter=0;
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (counter==5) yield return item;
                counter = predicate(item) ? counter + 1 : 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like others have mentioned, LINQ is not the ideal solution to this kind of pattern matching need. But still, it is possible, and it doesn't have to be ugly:

```
Func<int, bool> isBody = n => n == 8;
Func<int, bool> isEnd = n => n == 2;
var requiredBodyLength = 5;

//    Index:       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
int[] sequence = { 6, 8, 8, 9, 2, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 5 };
//                                         ^-----------^  ^
//                                             Body      End

// First we stick an index on each element, since that's the desired output.
var indexedSequence = sequence.Select((n, i) => new { Index = i, Number = n }).ToArray();

// Scroll to the right to see comments
var patternMatchIndexes = indexedSequence
    .Select(x => indexedSequence.Skip(x.Index).TakeWhile(x2 => isBody(x2.Number)))             // Skip all the elements we already processed and try to match the body
    .Where(body => body.Count() == requiredBodyLength)                                         // Filter out any body sequences of incorrect length
    .Select(body => new { BodyIndex = body.First().Index, EndIndex = body.Last().Index + 1 })  // Prepare the index of the first body element and the index of the end element
    .Where(x => x.EndIndex < sequence.Length && isEnd(sequence[x.EndIndex]))                   // Make sure there is at least one element after the body and that it's an end element
    .Select(x => x.BodyIndex)                                                                  // There may be more than one matching pattern, get all their indices
    .ToArray();

//patternMatchIndexes.Dump();   // Uncomment in LINQPad to see results
```

**Note that this implementation is not performant at all, it is only meant as a teaching aid to show how something can be done in LINQ despite the unsuitability of solving it that way**.